# Install dependencies for a bash script

Tags: shell-script, make, dependencies

I've recently made a bash script that can be downloaded and installed by users via a `Makefile`. The problem is that I'm not sure how to have dependencies get installed. In this case, the only dependency is `jq`. One method I thought might work would be to just run `sudo apt-get install jq` in the bash script itself when it detects that `jq` isn't installed, but this wouldn't work on all distros, since not all of them use `apt` as their package managers. What would be the ideal way to install a dependency in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either make one script for each distribution you support or if you want to propose only one script for all, you will need to detect the OS version in your script to choose then if you want to run apt, yum or other

Comment: I suppose this could be a solution, thanks